# g++ not able to create object file, .o no such file or directory

Tags: g++

Trying to learn makefiles on my own, I'm getting this strange behavior (but maybe not so strange for you :-) )

I have a simple helloworld project with only 1 source file.
g++ is able to create the exe file directly wit command
`g++ main.cc -o main`

but if I want g++ to not link and only create the o file with command `g++ main.cc -c main.o`, I'm getting a strange error saying that the o file is not found, where as I'm trying to generate it:

```
local@Tcomputer ~/Documents/1_HelloWorld (branch_1_source_file)$ g++ main.cc -c main.o
g++: error: main.o: No such file or directory
```

I overlook on the web and the g++ man page, and the command seems right to me...
I'm expecting the main.o file to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution: not specifying the output file:

```
g++ main.cc -c
```

but this strange that the tutorial I use is not working. g++ use may have changed.